# Restarting Sprite - Kit Game Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a simple 2D arcade game using SpriteKit and I am trying to add a scoring system.Basically the game is a square sprite which has to jump over various obstacles. So what I want is when the player contacts the object for the whole game to restart. The game detects the contact (I tested it previously) but when I remove all my children and then run my game's basic main function I notice that old objects keep spawning and cluttering with each other.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Obstacles ) { //case where PLAYER collides with OBSTACLE

        print("I detect Contact")

        Scorelabel.text = "0"
        scoreCounter = 0


        self.removeAllActions()
        self.removeAllChildren()

        self.setupGame()

    }
```

// the didBeging func is then continued for other cases

`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question: it's not clear if you want to implement a simple game over or the loss of a life (where for example you should come back to a previous situation without reload the full scene). Anyway, if you want a game over  you should follow the Nik answer's otherwise you should correct your properties to represent an old state. You shouldn't do in didBegin(_contact) because it could be called many times (your code is wrong..)

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I believe what you said about it being called multiple times is what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to restart a scene, you can just present the same scene and it resets back to its defaults:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: self.size) // Whichever scene you want to restart (and are in)
let animation = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.5) // ...Add transition if you like
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: animation)
```

Put this code in whichever scene you are in and wish to restart. It should be called when you want to restart the scene.

You might just want to not show an animation (or do a cross fade) if you're trying to make a seamless transition.

Alternatively, you may want to create a game over scene/menu. This could just be another SKNode that becomes visible once the game resets or even another scene.

Comment: This is how I recommend resetting,  it allows you to start a new game fresh, which means no previous game data could carry over into the new game and corrupt the state

Comment: @Confused Wherever you want to restart the scene

Comment: In the GameScene?

Comment: @Confused Whichever scene you're already in (and want to restart)

Comment: Cheers. That's the part was confusing me.

Comment: @Confused Great. I'll update the answer to be more clear

Answer (score 2):

First of All, you should check both cases, If player is Contact A or if Player is Contact B.
Secondly, you should assign the object you want to remove, lets says the obstacle, to a variable, for example lets says that Object B es the Obstacle, Then: contact.bodyB.node.removeFromParent() and you will successfully remove the object.

Comment: I believe I was not very clear. My goal is to completely restart my game. I do not just want to remove the given obstacle but everything. As for the other contact case, I have implemented it into my code but I just didn't add it as part of my question so it looked neater

Comment: In That Case you can do it like this on your game scene:
let newGame = GameScene(size: self.size)
            newGame.viewController = self.viewController
            self.viewController.currentGame = newGame
            self.changePlayer()
            newGame.currentPlayer = self.currentPlayer
            let transition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 1.5)
            self.view?.presentScene(newGame, transition: transition)