# Reset SKScene in Sprite Kit Game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I am working on a game.

My 1st screen include 3 buttons : leaderboards, achievements and play.

When I tap on play, the Game Scene is showed.

```
let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
let next_scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
next_scene?.scaleMode = scaleMode
view?.presentScene(next_scene!, transition: transition)
```

When the user dies, I want to reset the game scene, that includes erasing everything and calling didMove function again. I want to erase game scene and create it again.

How can I do this?

I tried

```
self.view?.presentScene(nil)
let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
let next_scene = MainMenu(size: self.size)
next_scene.scaleMode = scaleMode
self.view?.presentScene(next_scene, transition: transition)
```

but made the scene blank with 0 nodes.

Comment: have you tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41649738/4056108)

Comment: Tried that solution, but the problem is that it doesn't reset me scene. It fades it out, and when it fades in it continues the scene. It doesn't start from scratch, it starts where it was the last time, with game over menu and others.

Comment: Based on what you've said this answer (by me) should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40052923/6728196. Also, why are you presenting the MainMenu if you said you want to restart the GameScene?

Comment: Tried, but without success. 

'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'moon' and it happens for all other Nodes. The problem is that when I restart the scene it doesn't erase my nodes. It erase everything except 2 nodes.

Comment: Are you using the sks file? You probably want to do `let next_scene = MenuScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene")`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way: `

```
  let gameSceneTemp = sceneName(fileNamed: "fileName")
                gameSceneTemp?.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
                self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameSceneTemp!, transition: SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.0))`
```

I also sometimes create objects not in SKScenes files, and if you are using addChild, you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this other method:

```swift
///Makes a new copy of itself and presents it to be able to "reset" a scene.
func startAgain() {
   guard let newScene = (self.mutableCopy() as? GameScene) else {
      return // it wasn’t able to turn the scene into the specified type
   }
   self.view!.presentScene(newScene, transition: SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.2))
}
```

And I think that should work. Tell me (if possible) if this solution worked to anyone